# Chrome Extension upload error - default_locale missing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Whenever I try to upload my updated extension to the Chrome Web Store I get a "default_locale field is missing in manifest." error, yet it is clearly located in my manifest (pasted below).

Any pointers for how I can resolve this?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "####",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "default_locale": "en-US",
  "description": "####",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/icon16.png",
    "48": "icons/icon48.png",
    "64": "icons/icon64.png",
    "128": "icons/icon128.png"
  },
  "homepage_url": "http://####.com",
  "permissions": [
    "https://*.####.com/*",
    "https://####.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://*.####.com/*",          
        "https://####.com/*"
      ],
      "css": [
        "src/####/####.css"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Typo? The [documentation says](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-locales) an underscore should be used: `en_US`. Also make sure the language directory actually exists inside `_locales` and contains a valid messages.json

Comment: Thanks, the typo catch helped but as it's core creating the _locales directory seem to be what it needed

Comment: Extensionizr creates an `en` locale by default. If you're not using localization, you can remove both `default_locale` and the `_locales` directory. Having one or the other will result in the same "default_locale missing" error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the Web Store wanted a _locales directory added to the root with subfolders ("en_US" for my case) and accompanied by properly setup messages.json files. Following the information from the [Localizing your app](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/i18n#details) guide resolved the issue.

Hoping Google can change their error message be something like "_locales directory not found" rather than the manifest error we currently receive.

Comment: Added to the root of what exactly? I have one in the root of my extension, but Google still gives this useless error message.

Comment: @Slbox "You localize the name and description by modifying manifest.json and providing a _locales directory in your app's ZIP file." so if you are getting an error double check those are both at the root of the .zip, otherwise I'd try to post with more info to help track down an answer