# Unable to publish Edge browser extension: Package acceptance validation error

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge

**Update 2: Microsoft fixed the bug.**

I'm trying to publish an Edge browser extension, but I'm getting the following error:

The following checks failed: Package acceptance validation error: Localization directory for default_locale en not found under _locales directory.

I have this directory, though:

```
gmike:tablecapture gmike$ grep default_locale manifest.json
  "default_locale": "en",
gmike:tablecapture gmike$ ls _locales/en/messages.json
_locales/en/messages.json
gmike:tablecapture gmike$
```

I can't figure out how to fix this and my only thought is that it's a bug in the manifest/package validation, but I don't know.

Thoughts?

Update: I added the zip file here:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/discussions/issues-publishing-edge-extension/m-p/1203880

Comment: Without seeing the full manifest.json I'd say this sounds like a bug in their server.

Comment: Added a link to the other post I made about this issue, which has the zip file I later added that produced the same error. It's basically a no-op extension.

Comment: Yep, definitely a bug in their software.

Comment: I reproduced the issue on my side. I found out [a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942845/chrome-extension-upload-error-default-locale-missing) but it seems that you have done the right things. I'll try to investigate deeper and discuss with senior engineers and inform you if there's any update. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou - I've opened a ticket (SRX1495925929ID) if you plan on following up on this internally at Microsoft.

Comment: Nevermind. They closed it. Whatever.

Comment: This seems to be a issue with the Edge side. I also provide a feedback to Microsoft about this issue. Let's wait and see if there's any update.

Comment: There was an update from Elliot - looks like it's been fixed now!

Comment: So glad you have solved the issue!